# Framed pages with a special layout/geometry for the first page and a general layout/geometry

Tags: tikz-pgf, two-column, pagestyle

I try to create a two columns document with two styles of frames for the pages.

The goal is to have a structure that looks like this (ignore the text) : [image]
[image]
[image]

I tried to define two pagestyles : The first one would have a geometry such that the left margin is 3.2cm, and there would be two boxes and one big frame drawn with tikz like in the goal. I would use `\thispagestyle` command to define the first page's style.

The second pagestyle would be the general pagestyle i.e. every page style after the first one, it would just be a big frame with 1cm margins a scaled geometry for it.

My attempt doesn't work and just overflows the text outside the frame.

MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles,explicit]{titlesec}
\geometry{left=3.2cm,right=1.2cm,top=1.2cm,bottom=1.2cm,footskip=0.7cm,landscape,twocolumn}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newpagestyle{firstpagestyle}[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[line width=3pt]($(current page.north west)+(3cm,-1cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-1cm,1cm)$);
\draw[]($(current page.north west)+(1cm,-1cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south west)+(2cm,3cm)$);
\draw[]($(current page.south west)+(1cm,1cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south west)+(2cm,2.5cm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newpagestyle{generalpagestyle}[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[line width=3pt]($(current page.north west)+(1cm,-1cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-1cm,1cm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newgeometry{left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,top=1.2cm,bottom=1.2cm,footskip=0.7cm,twocolumn}
}
\begin{document}
%\thispagestyle{firstpagestyle}
\pagestyle{generalpagestyle}
\section{Example of section}
\subsection{Example of subsection}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be better to post an image here instead of linking. Some people will not follow a potentially malicious link and the contents are, in any case, liable to disappear or alter, marooning your question. Just looking at your code, this isn't going to work. `\newgeometry` starts a new page. So you could use it at the end of your first page, but you shouldn't put it in a page style. Moreover, it sounds as if you only want to change the page layout (as opposed to the style) once, whereas the style gets applied on every page. Basically page layout and page style are quite distinct things.

Comment: I edited my post as suggested. Yes I just want to change the layout. After the first page, I need to redefine the geometry and I also want to apply automatically the overlay tikzpicture environment to have a frame on every page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this: the background picture and the page layout. The first is easy; the second is harder.

For the pictures, I use a one-time hook to insert a box containing the first `tikzpicture` and a standard hook for a box containing the second. Using a box rather than including the code for the `tikzpicture` directly means we're only using LaTeX's `picture` environment to actually insert it. For the second picture, that is much more efficient than invoking a `tikzpicture` each time, especially for a simple frame. (You could do without `tikzpicture` and use something simpler if you only want a frame. But this isn't really a concern if you're doing it only once and boxing it.)

The change in page layout is trickier. You could approach it in various ways, each of which has its limitations.

- You can use `\newgeometry` in the body of the document. This will insert a page break at the point it is used.
- You could try to do that automatically, but the page break is unavoidable.
- You could adjust the page layout with `changepage`, inserting a suitable command at an appropriate point. In this case it probably makes sense to set up `geometry` for the standard case. Here you have the choice of enforcing a page break or tolerating a mis-formatted partial paragraph, because the change is only possible between paragraphs.
- So the best result might be obtained if you organise the content so that a page break occurs naturally e.g. a section break or something like that. The example below demonstrates this option.
- If you make this happen at a natural break, there are also ways of automating the change to the page layout. For example, some solutions use a `geometry` change with `fancyhdr`. But this would break things if you use the `titlesec` stuff in other ways.
- Altering the page layout and/or `geometry` is straightforward if you can arrange it at a paragraph break.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\geometry{left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,top=1.2cm,bottom=1.2cm,footskip=0.7cm}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{%
    \put (0,-\paperheight) {\usebox \backgroundfirst}%
  }%
  \changetext{}{-2cm}{2cm}{2cm}{}%
  \AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{%
    \AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
      \put (0,-\paperheight) {\usebox \backgroundgeneral}%
    }%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand \pagelayoutgeneral {} {%
  \clearpage
  \changetext{}{2cm}{-2cm}{-2cm}{}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newsavebox{\backgroundfirst}
\sbox \backgroundfirst {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(nw)]
    \coordinate (nw) at (0,0);
    \path  (nw)  ++(3cm,-1cm);
    \draw[line width=3pt]($(current page.north west)+(3cm,-1cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-1cm,1cm)$);
    \draw[]($(current page.north west)+(1cm,-1cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south west)+(2cm,3cm)$);
    \draw[]($(current page.south west)+(1cm,1cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south west)+(2cm,2.5cm)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}%  
}
\newsavebox \backgroundgeneral
\sbox \backgroundgeneral {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(nw)]
    \coordinate (nw) at (0,0);
    \path  (nw)  ++(1cm,-1cm);
    \draw[line width=3pt]($(current page.north west)+(1cm,-1cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-1cm,1cm)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\section{Example of section}
\subsection{Example of subsection}
\kant[1-6]
\pagelayoutgeneral
\kant[7-20]
\end{document}
```

`changepage` claims changes 'sometimes' work if included with `\afterpage{}` from the `afterpage` package or in headings as part of a page style. However I could not get this to work.

[image: switched page layouts]

[The blurriness on the last page is due to a limitation of Okular and not the actual appearance.]